# Sending message from GAE server to a client program

Tags: google-app-engine

My GAE application has a server-side program (run in Google App Engine) and a client-side program. Is there any elegant way to send message from the server to the client program? The socket is not allowed in GAE and the channel API is not applicable since the client program is not a browser. The only way I can think of is to let the client program check the server status from time to time (like every 5 seconds). The program is that it eats up the expensive frontend instance hours even only memcache is used. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice your comment until now. I think XMPP is what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via XMPP API. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview

Comment: Look like what I am looking for: low cost and no third-party services involved. I'll try it out later. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com) where you can find lots of [examples/tutorials](http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter#tutorials) in various platforms. It's pretty easy to integrate it with just few lines of code and you'll have push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`pubsubhubbub`](https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) community server at http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/ to push updates to your client.

Comment: Pubsubhubbub is still http based, so there is no real push. It's poll based, but pollling is "smart", i.e. poll interval is adapted based on hub activity: https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/WhyPollingSucks

Comment: @PeterKnego Yes, but the polling doesn't against the OP's own frontend.

Comment: So to summarize this, the "client" can run its own simple HTTP server, and provide a URL to the GAE app.  The GAE app can then use urlfetch to send HTTP requests to the client.